# Review triage questions accordingly to my favorite tags

Tags: discussion, feature-request, triage, filtering

I had read some topics here, made some triage reviews, and I am still not sure that my reviews are good enough. I often see questions, that have all signs of a good question, but they are about language that I don't know (PHP or ASP.NET, for example).

In this case, I often have doubts: do the question have full information about the problem? Often such questions have comments, where other users are asking more details, and in this case I prefer to choose "Should be improved". Of course, when I see questions about Oracle or SQL, I have no any doubts (because I know them enough).

So here is my suggestion: when user wants to make triage review, to give him (if possible) questions with the same tags, that are in "Tags" section of user's profile. If user prefer to answer questions with certain tags, then probably he knows them better and he could make better review.

Comment: Regarding if you have doubts, skip. If you can tell clearly, even with the language barrier, that it could be improved or sacked, such as asking for a resource, then I don't see why you shouldn't. I don't believe there are enough questions in Triage for filtering to be practical, plus the questions may be incorrectly tagged anyways.

Comment: @Compass I thought about that (both about "skip" and "is there enough questions"). I think, when I press "skip", in fact I do that automated filtering job manually (of course, it is not hard for me). Also, if there is enough of users to answer, it has to be enough users to review filtered questions. In any case, I am not insisting.

Comment: I would actually like to see this for all review queues. Particularly the Close queue. I know you can filter by tag, and enter up to 3 tags. But I think an option to quickly filter by favorite tags would be great.

Comment: Why would the triage queue be exceptional compared to VLW, first, last, etc posts?

Comment: @lpapp I suggested this feature for triage because it seems to me, that triage is a sort of review which needs this feature more than others. But It shouldn't be an exception, here I agree with opinion of Reto Koradi above.